# How to get accurate position from GPS periodically

Tags: android, networking, gps, position

In application I need to get geo position of phone every x minutes (for now it's 5min and 50m), in such a way that phone doesn't discharge during day. The accuracy of position must be at least 40m. By now I have listeners for gps and network. The problem lies in the fact that the data I can receive sometimes is totally wrong (depends on phone) - new position can be even 200m from my real position and with 40m accuracy; next point can be the same but in opposite direction. For my app it's fatally. 
So the question is next: Is there any way to get more accuracy data but not very often?

Update 1: to show the problem in action:

[image]

(The phone is lying in the fixed position)

Comment: if your GPS is telling you that the accuracy is 40m when it really is 200m off, there isn't much you can do, except change GPS. (you could go into correlation, filtering and cross referencing with speed, gathering a bunch of points and accumulating them into a single piece of information, but that's a lot of work)

Comment: When the GPS is 200m off, then either it is not GPS, or the device was used indoors.If you need acurate, excluivly use GPS_PROVIDER. The phone will discharge, you cannot have both acurate and no discharge.

Answer (score 0):

To get more accurate location make sure you're using the    ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in your manifest. To prevent higher battery usage, you can use setInterval and setFastestInterval on your LocationRequest object. Longer intervals mean less battery usage by your app.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be accessing the gps and network directly, you should be using [`LocationManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html) and using `ACCURACY_FINE` in your [`Criteria`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Criteria.html). This will help conserve battery life, and avoid issues with phones where the gps may have been disabled. There's more detail on that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).

As far as the accuracy of your location, you can use `Location`'s `getAccuracy` method to get Android's estimate of how accurate a measurement is. If it doesn't fit your criteria, discard it and poll again.